# ng-repeat not working with checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

the text field is shown based on the radio button selected. Now i change it to the checkbox its not working. Any help pls.

```
   <body ng-app="EquityCompensation">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-route.js"></script>
     <script src="app.js"></script>
     <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="choic in choice">
      <form>
        <input ng-model="choic.mustShow" class="label_align" type="checkbox"    name="customer" value="no">
        <div class="mediumSubhead"> Information housed </div>
        <br/>
        <input ng-model="choic.mustShow" class="label_align" type="checkbox" name="customer" value="yes">
        <div class="mediumSubhead"> Information housed outside </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="(choice | filter: {mustShow: 'yes'}).length > 0">
      <input name="first_name" class="text_box_space" type="text" value=""       style="color: black;" size="25" width="200px">
      </div>
     </div>
      </body>
     var app = angular.module('EquityCompensation', []);
     app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.choice = [{id: 'choic1'},{id: 'choic2'}];
      });
```

Comment: Your code does what I expect it to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/MMwk9a4vm9w7FMF7GWTe?p=preview. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I want it to be checkbox instead of radio button. The text field is not working when i change radio to checkbox

Comment: Then show us the code which doesn't work, with the checkboxes. Not the code which works and we don't need to fix. When you go to the doctor because your son is sick, you don't go with your daughter, do you? You go with your son, because that's who the doctor needs to see. You also still haven't said what you expect your code to do.

Comment: cool. I did so . can you help now pls.

Comment: Now update the question with a better problem description than `doesn't work`. Problem description is not clear at all. A demo would also help

Comment: thanks I found the solution myself.

Answer (score 0):

ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'" used this attribute & it worked